# I am trying to setup a minio server with traefik but Share URLs are pointing to the internal network ip instead my domain

Tags: docker, traefik, lets-encrypt, minio

I have the exact same setup and issue from this link [Minio install behind Traefik](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69385638/14253379)

I was looking to fix this sharing URL actually pointing to some docker intenal URL

[image: URL not displaying my domain]

Obviously you must tell minio server what domain generated URLs should be pointint at.

But, in case I setup MINIO_SERVER_URL pointing to my domain I get random TLS errors and no certificates from letsencrypt.

There is random cases where I get the `console` and `server` domain certificates, but then I cannot login by the following error

[image: login error]

Hope I can get some insights regarding the amount of time I spent this weekend reading docks and bothering people everywhere

Comment: Same for me. Did you figure out how to solve it?

Comment: I ended up setting it up with https://nginxproxymanager.com/ 
I gave up with traefik.
Random TLS errors were caused by [raspbian DHCP kernel issue](https://github.com/minio/console/issues/1632#issuecomment-1072913494) which caused a weird docker internal network issue with DHCP.
Also raspberry pi lacks of hardware accelerated encription so whe you use it as reverse proxy it just sucks giving you high CPU on nginx usage while on HTTPS. 
I will post my docker compose template example to properly setup Nginx Proxy Manager with additive services sharing the same docker network!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried too many ways to come over this issue and ended with this solution:
https://forum.cloudron.io/post/46317

> I got the solution for configuring the domain in the MinIO docker
> container:
>
> Just make these changes in the mino.env
>
> ```
> MINIO_SITE_NAME=***
> MINIO_SITE_REGION=***
> MINIO_ROOT_USER=***
> MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
> MINIO_SERVER_URL=https://api.example.com
> MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL=https://minio.example.com
> ```

After implementing the fix, it worked as expected.